# Choosing between Select and Where in Lambda

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, lambda

What is the difference between:

```
var UR = context.UserResearches.Select(c => c.SessionID == SessionID).First();

var UR = context.UserResearches.Where(c => c.SessionID == SessionID).First();
```

Comment: First one will return a bool but the second your class.

Comment: What did you find out when you looked at the documentation of each method, and what in that documentation did you find confusing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) will map one sequence to another—returning a sequence that contains the result of the lambda expression when called on each item:

```
var UR = context.UserResearches.Select(c => c.SessionID == SessionID).First();
```

This will get a sequence like `{ False, False, False, True, False, False }` then return the first item from that sequence.

---

[`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the other hand will filter a sequence, returning only those elements where the lambda expression evaluates to `True`:

```
var UR = context.UserResearches.Where(c => c.SessionID == SessionID).First();
```

This will get a sequence of `UserResearch` objects containing only those objects where `SessionID == SessionID` then return the first item from that sequence.

<sup>Note: Linq uses [lazy evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx), so `First` will cause it to stop evaluating the rest of the sequence after the first element is found.</sup>

Comment: Also note that the rest of the sequence is never evaluated. As soon as an item is found, First() will terminate the enumeration.

Comment: @Dennis_E Good point. I tried to word my answer in a way that made it clear what was happening *conceptually*, but I can see where that could lead to some confusion for readers not familiar with how Linq works under the hood. I've included a note on that for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

```
Where
```

will select all UserResearch that match SessionID

```
Select
```

will create a list of boolean results.  Each bool value in that list will be for each UserResearch and if they match the SessionID